# OpenVPN failover

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, failover

In my company we have two offices in two totally different locations. A is the main office, and B is the secondary. There is a VPN server at A office, and every computer access the A network via this OpenVPN server. Last year we had some error with the VPN server and the people couldn't work in the B office because that. My question is there a failover method for OpenVPN? We want to setup an other VPN server, but how we solve the failover part, if something would happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my clients depends heavily on OpenVPN over a multi-site setup, and we take two approaches:

1. The main OpenVPN service is provided by two machines, in an HA-failover pair using heartbeat/CRM.  If one goes down, the other takes over the shared IP addresses, and service continues.  Existing sessions will be dropped, but the clients usually reauthenticate automatically, and we have found this is fairly painless for users in practice.
2. The second site also has a working OpenVPN endpoint, and all users have a second config for backup.  If the internet conection to the main site goes down, they can point their OpenVPN clients at the second config, and some semblance of normal life can continue.

If you do this, and you use username/password authentication of the user as well as certificate-based authentication of the endpoint, we've found that it's quite important to federate the authentication environment (eg, authenticate via LDAP).  Otherwise users forget their access tokens on the infrequently-used endpoints, or fail to update them everywhere, and any failover triggers a deluge of "*my password doesn't work*" calls.

The federated service should be provided with a similar degree of resiliency as the OpenVPN servers themselves, otherwise all you've done is upstream your SPOF.

Answer (score -1):

> We want to setup an other VPN server, but how we solve the failover part, if something would happen.

Ok. If you using Linux , then

1) Simple way is use monit https://mmonit.com/monit/

2) Bash script in cron like my https://github.com/darkhex/bash_scripts/blob/master/work-scripts/check_vpn.sh

3) Zabbix with triggers

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to setup a high availability (failover) cluster.
You would like to have a virtual IP that will be the ip used as gateway by your vpn client. This IP will be migrated on the standby server by the cluster if case of failure and the cluster will start openvpn on the stand-by server.
I have written a failover cluster manager in shell script, have a look at it
and if you need support contact me directly (look at the code for my email).
https://github.com/nackstein/back-to-work/

I think the code is elegant and still compact to be understood even by on expert sysadmin. It's a much better solution than schedule a crontab script since with my cluster you will complitely avoid split brain situation. 
The only drawback is that it need 3 pc to work (other cluster software use a shared storage for quorum or STONITH approach like RedHat cluster but IHMO is a ugly solution). With only 2 node you cannot avoid split brain in case of server fault, it's math :)

Comment: Distributed systems are *hard*.  Homebrew HA cluster managers are fraught with peril.

Comment: if you had taken a look at the code before judging you would not say so.

Comment: I did take a look at the code.  Distributed systems are still hard, and homebrew HA cluster managers are still fraught with peril.

Comment: Why do you even need a complicated HA cluster manager? All you need is a VRRP implementation such as keepalived. OpenVPN has built-in dead connection detection; just enable that. Sure, split brain can happen but that's not really a problem with OpenVPN -- either the routing works or it doesn't. It's not like there's a ton of complicated server state.